# ASP.NET 5, Entity Framework 7 & SQL Server 2014 - multiple dbContexts, SQL views

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dbcontext, asp.net-core, sql-server-2014, entity-framework-core

I have created a solution in Visual Studio 2015 consisting of a Web project (using the ASP.NET 5 Beta 6 Web Application Preview Template), and a Model project (using Entity Framework 7 Beta 6).

I got to the point where I could get data from a SQL Server database and display it on a page. Then, I wanted to try pulling data from two different databases, but ran into issues when trying to use more than one dbContext.

In Startup.cs, I add the EF service and add a dbContext, which works fine. But I'm not sure how to add more than one... the code below is how I attempted to add another, but the second AddDbContext just seems to overwrite the first.

I also ran into another issue somewhat related to this.. I was not able to get data from a SQL view. I've confirmed that the view does contain data, but when I write a WebAPI method to get data from that view, the response contains nothing. In past projects using EF6, I've had no problem modeling views and retrieving data from them.

**To summarize my questions:**

1. How do you set up multiple dbContexts in an ASP.NET 5 web project using EF7?
2. How do you model a SQL Server view in EF7?

---

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // Setup configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

// This method gets called by a runtime.
// Use this method to add services to the container
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Register Entity Framework
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyContextA>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:AConnectionString"])
        )
        .AddDbContext<MyContextB>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:BConnectionString"])
        );

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

**config.json**

```js
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "AConnectionString": "data source=xxxxxxx;initial catalog=xxxxxxxx;Uid=xxxxxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxx;",
      "BConnectionString": "data source=xxxxxxx;initial catalog=xxxxxxxx;Uid=xxxxxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxx;"
    }
  },
  "EntityFramework": {
    "MyContextA": {
      "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnection:AConnectionString"
    },
    "MyContextB": {
      "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnection:BConnectionString"
    }
  }
}
```

**MyContextA.cs**

```cs
public class MyContextA : DbContext
{
    public MyContextA (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Some_View> Some_View { get; set; }
}
```

**MyContextB.cs**

```cs
public class MyContextB : DbContext
{
    public MyContextB (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Some_View.cs**

```cs
public class Some_View
{
    public int SomeField { get; set; }
    public int AnotherField { get; set; }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyContextA _dbContext;

    // Constructor
    public TestController(MyContextA dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Some_View> Get()
    {
        var data = _dbContext.Some_View;
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am able to get everything to work with one dbContext and using regular tables such as Product in the example above. But when I try to use the view I get no data, and when I use multiple contexts the second context overrides the first.

Comment: What "things just aren't working properly"? What is the behavior you expect to see? Error messages? etc.

Comment: No error messages, just no data in the response when I use a view. Also, if I add two dbContexts in Startup.cs, it uses the second context instead of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, this isn't an issue anymore with .NET Core and EF Core 1.0.0. The following is how I registered each dbcontext in my Web API Startup.cs.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddDbContext<Context1>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Connection1"]));
    services.AddDbContext<Context2>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Connection2"]));
    // ...
}
```

**appsettings.DEVELOPMENT.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection1": "[connection string here]",
    "Connection2": "[connection string here]",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the constructors of your `DbContext`s to look like this:

```cs
public MyContextA (DbContextOptions<MyContextA> options) : base(options) { }
public MyContextB (DbContextOptions<MyContextB> options) : base(options) { }
```

Try calling `ToList()`

```cs
return data.ToList();
```

Each of these may be bugs you'll want to file on the [EF](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new) and [MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/new) repos.

Comment: ToList() throws an exception, and editing the constructors didn't seem to affect anything. Thanks for the suggestions, will check out the EF and MVC repos as well.

Comment: Looks like [view support in EF7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/827) is not there yet.

Comment: It supports views. They're no different than tables during query, and if they're updatable views, they're not different during update.

Comment: By applying specific type for DbContextOptions solved my problem. Without DbContextOptions<MyContextA> & DbContextOptions<MyContextB> MyContextB overrides MyContextA in StartUp.cs.